# Tengo problema con la función RETURN

Tags: python, print

Me estoy iniciando en la programación Python y no puedo utlizar bien la función 'return' en un pequeño programa de encriptación. Aquí lo muestro para ver si alguién de buena voluntad me enseña a solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias

```
def encriptar(texto):

    textoFinal = ''
    for letra in texto:
        ascii = ord(letra)
        ascii += 1
        textoFinal += chr(ascii)
        return textoFinal
print(textoFinal)

encriptar('Soy un estudiante de Python')

def desencriptar(texto):

    textoFinal = ''
    for letra in texto:
        ascii = ord(letra)
        ascii -= 1
        textoFinal += chr(ascii)
    print(textoFinal)

desencriptar('')
```

Cuando utilizo print(textoFinal) en def encriptar(texto) me trabaja bien, pero le pongo la función return textoFinal y no me muestra nada el programa

Comment: El `return` va fuera del `for`.

Comment: Nota de terminología. `return` no es una función, es una sentencia

Comment: Creo que como menciona @candidmoe así como pusiste la identación para `print` en `desencriptar` deberías de hacerlo en la función encriptar, pero también si vas a utilizar return y print, deberías de cambiar el orden para que print esté antes del `return`. Como está escrito `print(textoFinal)` arroja una exepción `NameError` porque la variable está en el ámbito de la función `encriptar`.  Yo te sugiero que no utilizes print en las funciones, solo utiliza `return` al final  y después puedes usar `print(desencriptar(texto))`  y `print(encriptar(texto))`

Comment: también podrías usar `texto_cifrado = encriptar("texto a encriptar")` para después `print(texto_cifrado)` y  `texto = desencriptar(texto_cifrado)`  `print(texto)`

Answer (score 1):

El código que presentas puede escribirse de manera más compacta en Python que en otros lenguajes primitivos:

```
def encriptar(texto):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(letra) + 1) for letra in texto])

def desencriptar(texto):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(letra) - 1) for letra in texto])
```

Hay varias partes en el `return`. Primero, tenemos una comprensión de lista:

```
[chr(ord(letra) + 1) for letra in texto]
```

Es similar a este código

```
lista = []
for letra in texto:
    nueva = chr(ord(letra) + 1)
    lista.append(nueva)
```

La comprensión genera una lista de caracteres, los que unimos usando `join()`.

**Optimización**

En realidad no necesitamos crear la lista completa para luego concatenarla en una pura cadena. Podemos usar una *expresión generadora* que vaya entregando las letras una por una:

```
def encriptar(texto):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(letra) + 1) for letra in texto)

def desencriptar(texto):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(letra) - 1) for letra in texto)
```

La *expresión generadora* es la misma comprensión de listas sin los cuadrentesis `[]`.

#### Demo

```
def encriptar(texto):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(letra) + 1) for letra in texto)

def desencriptar(texto):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(letra) - 1) for letra in texto)

enc = encriptar('Soy un estudiante de Python')
print(f"Texto encriptado {enc}")
des = desencriptar(enc)
print(f"Texto desencriptado {des}")
```

produce:

```
Texto encriptado Tpz!vo!ftuvejbouf!ef!Qzuipo
Texto desencriptado Soy un estudiante de Python

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Es debido a varias cosas, intentaré explicarlo de la mejor manera.
**return** es una instrucción que devuelve un valor, pero que lo devuelva no significa que lo dibuje (print) en pantalla, solo quiere decir que te devuelve el valor fuera de la función.

Por esa razón cúando usas "**print**" en la función "**desencriptar**" si te muestra el valor y en encriptar no.
Pero támbien tienes otro error en el código, y es que el return está dentro del bucle for.

Para que funcione como quieres, deberías poner algo así:

```
def encriptar(texto):

    textoFinal = ''
    for letra in texto:
        ascii = ord(letra)
        ascii += 1
        textoFinal += chr(ascii)
    return textoFinal # Aquí el return está fuera del bucle for
```

Si ahora quieres que se muestre en pantalla el "resultado" de la función deberías inicializarla así

```
print(encriptar("Lo que sea"))
```

Esto es un ejemplo muy básico y hay diferentes formas de hacerlo (obviamente), pero espero que te haya servido para comprender un poco más como usar el "**return**"

Comment: Return no es una función (tal y como indicaron en un comentario de la pregunta).